# AEM component not displayed on Preview Mode

Tags: aem

I have developed a few components for AEM but I just ran into an issue. One of the components I created is not displaying when I append the wcmmode=disabled flag. It works great on edit mode but once I pass the flag the component and contents are gone, this is the first time that this happens.

If it helps the component that I created is an extension of the column control component from AEM and it automatically adds children to it.

URL example in Edit Mode:
http://localhost:4502/cf#/content/location/file.html

URL example with WCMMODE flag set to disabled:
http://localhost:4502/content/location/url.html?wcmmode=disabled

Comment: The question contains limited information to provide a solution. It is more of a guess work to be done rather than letting know the solution. Would be helpful if further information such as sample code, snapshots etc. are added to the question

Comment: Have you looked at the generated html source? Often there's some kind of exception. Also check the logfile

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added more detailed information and in fact the component works on preview mode. It only fails when I am looking at it with the wcmmode=disabled flag. I was looking at the source code and it is not added when the flag is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Column Control (sightly version) as a guide and figured out that the following code was what was causing the issue:

if (typeof wcmmode != "undefined" && wcmmode.isEdit())

Thank you for helping me debug this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ContentWrapper').resize()  / $(document).resize();
```

Try this code in your JS file. Once document ready, resize method will get updated component invisible portion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the CSS issue . Can you inspect element &check .some times "float:left,right" cause this issue .